# Execute SQLite script

Tags: sqlite

I start up sqlite3 version 3.7.7, unix 11.4.2 using this command:

```
sqlite3 auction.db
```

where auction.db has not already been created.

```
sqlite> auction.db < create.sql;
```

gives me this error: `near "auction": syntax error`

How can I run the script?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, one way is:

`sqlite3 auction.db`

Followed by:

`sqlite> .read create.sql`

In general, the SQLite project has really fantastic documentation! I know we often reach for Google before the docs, but in SQLite's case, the docs really are technical writing at its best. It's clean, clear, and concise.

Comment: For use in scritps, you can run the `.read` command directly from the `sqlite3` command: `sqlite3 autction.db '.read create.sql'`.

Comment: See [Command Line Shell For SQLite: 7.2. Reading SQL from a file](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#reading_sql_from_a_file).

Comment: For Windows CMD line it is important to use doublequotes for the `".read script.sql"` part. With single quotes you get an `Error: in prepare, unrecognized token: "'.read"`

Answer (score 218):

You want to feed the `create.sql` into `sqlite3` from the shell, not from inside SQLite itself:

```
$ sqlite3 auction.db < create.sql
```

SQLite's version of SQL doesn't understand `<` for files, your shell does.

Comment: Unfortunately, not all shells understand `<` as input redirection.  (E.g., PowerShell.)

Comment: @Alan PowerShell has some input redirection mechanism, no? And if not there's always [bitops's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11643733/479863) approach.

Comment: @muistooshort see my comment to bitops. The sqlite dot commands work in the sql statement parameter so you can .read the file you want without resorting to input redirection.

Comment: @ChrisBecke they are different solutions. `<` will exit the SQLite prompt immediately and return the error code to the shell. `.read file.sql` will leave the prompt up and `-init file.sql` will always return 0, so `<` is the best for scripting. Also it's cross-platform unlike `.read` which doesn't support Windows paths.

Answer (score 37):

In order to execute simple queries and return to my shell script, I think this works well:

```
$ sqlite3 example.db 'SELECT * FROM some_table;'
```

Comment: This is effectively _mu is too short_'s answer.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Yes, this is very close to _mu is too short_'s answer. The reason I added an additional answer was to demonstrate a method to quickly execute an inline command, rather than taking the additional step of creating an SQL file to store the command in.

Comment: @remeika I think the more idiomatic way to execute an inline command would be `sqlite3 example.db 'SELECT * FROM some_table;'`, rather than piping an echo

Comment: Also, (after the edit), it demonstrates that `sqlite3` reads commands to execute not only from `stdin`, but also from the last argument.

Answer (score 10):

For those using PowerShell

```bsh
PS C:\> Get-Content create.sql -Raw | sqlite3 auction.db
```

Answer (score 7):

```
sqlite3 -init create.sql auction.db .quit
```

When I enter the command `man sqlite3`, I see under "OPTIONS":

> **-init** *file*
>        Read and execute commands from *file* , which can contain a mix of SQL statements and meta-commands.

and under "SQLITE META-COMMANDS":

> .quit                    Exit this program

See also: [Command Line Shell For SQLite: 3. Special commands to sqlite3 (dot-commands)](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#special_commands_to_sqlite3_dot_commands_).

Also, when I enter the command `sqlite3 -help`, I see under "OPTIONS":

> -init FILENAME       read/process named file

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the windows CMD you can use this command to create a database using sqlite3

```
C:\sqlite3.exe DBNAME.db ".read DBSCRIPT.sql"
```

If you haven't a database with that name sqlite3 will create one, and if you already have one, it will run it anyways but with the "TABLENAME already exists" error, I think you can also use this command to change an already existing database (but im not sure)