# sqlite script is not executing from the command line

Tags: sqlite

I've referenced the following link for my problem [Execute SQLite script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643611/execute-sqlite-script) , but it doesn't seem to assist with my experience.

I am new to sqlite, and currently attempting to execute a create table script from the command line using the .read FILENAME function.. My code is the following:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE MovieList (ID   VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
 Title    VARCHAR(255),
 Studio   VARCHAR(255)            ,
 Released   VARCHAR(255)        ,
 Status   VARCHAR(30)             ,
 Sound    VARCHAR(30)             ,
 Versions   VARCHAR(10)         ,
 Price   VARCHAR(15)         ,
 Rating   VARCHAR(15)             ,
 Movie_Year   VARCHAR(5)      ,
 Genre  VARCHAR(30)         ,
 Aspect   VARCHAR(15)             ,
 UPC   VARCHAR(255)             ,
 Release_Date   VARCHAR(255)                ,
 Last_Updated   VARCHAR(255)                 
);
COMMIT;
```

The error I get is `Error: incomplete SQL: ??P` and I'm not too sure how to go about fixing this.  The alternative was to create the table and export the .dump file - and it had the same logic as above.  Is there something I may be missing?

Comment: How exactly did you create the file?

Comment: @CL. I initially created the script and got the error.  Thereafter I ran everything in the command prompt (which worked). Exported the file, and copied the structure into a new script, and got the same error.  I just want to understand why though.

Comment: Which editor? Which encoding?

Comment: @CL. sublime3 and UTF-8

Comment: I guess that editor stores a Byte-Order Mark at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL is correct, I've stored your script into `script.sql` and run:

```
sqlite3.exe my.db

sqlite> .read script.sql
sqlite> .exit
```

Db with required structure properly created. SQLite version 3.14.2

Typically `Error: incomplete SQL:` shows you statement with error. `??P` means something wrong at the beginning of your file. Open it in Notepad++, `View -> Show Symbol -> Show All Characters` and check what is wrong there.

Comment: Thanks for this - I've checked that and there was nothing obvious.  I did imagine that the beginning of the file would be an issue but found no solution.

Comment: I ended up creating a new n++ file and placing it in there.  It worked - but I still have no idea why :) 

Thanks.